# How to update the SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to insert the `web_salescart` table:

```
$insert_row = $conn->query(
    "INSERT INTO web_salescart (cartnumber, branchcode, stockid, qty, price, descr, salesman, date, time, brname,discount)                         
     VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CART']."', '".$_SESSION['BRANCHCODE']."', '".$item_data['stockid']."', '".$item_data['qty']."', '".$item_data['unit_price']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($item_data['description'])."', '".$_SESSION['salescode']."', '".date("m-d-y")."', '".date("g:i a")."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['BRNAME'])."','".$item_data['discount']."')");
```

Here `$item_data['discount']` is updating 33%. I need to update it as 0.33 in web_salescart table and 33% is the display figure. Can I use an update statement right after the INSERT so that $item_data['discount'] is divided by 100?

Comment: INSERT or UPDATE? Two different animals altogether.

Comment: *"Can I use an update statement right after the INSERT so that $item_data['discount'] is divided by 100?"* - Sure, use a multi-query. However, you're mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: It's getting inserted as 33%. On the table I want it is 0.33

Comment: Why is the discount column a string rather than a number?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` - that function doesn't work with OOP, as opposed to your MySQLi_ `$conn->query()` - edit: surprised you didn't catch that @Barmar

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't even look at the rest of his code, I just concerned myself with the question.

Comment: @Barmar I'm quite surprised that their code even works as they claim it does, unless they're not showing us their real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to `0.33` when you insert it, not as a separate query. In the query, replace `$item_data['discount']` with:

```
number_format(str_replace('%', '', $item_data['discount'])/100, 2)
```

Comment: What did it insert?

Comment: It didn't insert. I have a salesman app, just like amazon where the customer selects the products and adds to the cart. When I select the products and click add to cart it should be inserting this. After replacing the above it doesn't seem to like it. It doesn't add to the cart.

Comment: Is it getting an error? What's the value of `$insert_row`? If it's `false`, what does `echo $conn->error` show? These are basic debugging steps that you need to take.